# How to remove characters from an excel sheet?

Tags: c#, xml, excel

My overall problem is that I have a large Excel file(Column A-S, 85000 rows) that I want to convert to XML.  The data in the cells is all text.

The process I'm using now is to manually save the excel file as csv, then parse that in my own c# program to turn it into XML.  If you have better recommendations, please recommend. I've searched SO and the only *fast* methods I found for converting straight to XML require my data to be all numeric.
(Tried reading cell by cell, would have taken 3 days to process)

So, unless you can recommend a different way for me to approach the problem, I want to be able to programmatically remove all commas, <, >, ', and " from the excel sheet.

Comment: How are you connecting to Excel (Interop, Office Open XML, ODBC)? Did you know that Excel 2007 or later is already in XML and you can just transform it?

Comment: Although the input is Excel sheet ... any requirement that the processing be done in Excel? A little C# console app would do quite nicely here.

Comment: @Jetti Excel doc is xlsx. So 2007 and later. Before I went with the method of manually saving to csv, I was using ODBC

Comment: @DanielElliott Actually that's what I meant. I'd like to do this using a C# console app, without having to ever open the excel doc. Sorry, I should have specified

Comment: You could use Epplus to loop through all cells or rows and just do a string.remove or string.replace on those characters you mentioned above. http://epplus.codeplex.com/ I use Epplus for all my projects that need to interact with excel.

Comment: Then I'd have a look at the OpenXML SDK mentioned below. Reading it in with OpenXml, a little Linq to XML and then hey presto c# dealing with an IEnumerable of whatever. 85000 shouldnt be a speed issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and `XmlSerializer` to get the job done.

This is in light of the fact that a) you're using a console appilcation, and b) the interop assemblies are easy to integrate to the solution (just *References->Add*).

I'm assuming that you have a copy of Excel installed in the machine runnning the process (*you mentioned you manually open the workbook currently, hence the assumption*).

The code would look something like this:

*The serializable layer*:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public List<TestLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        LineItems = new List<TestLineItem>();
    }
}

public class TestLineItem
{
    private string SanitizeText(string input)
    {
        return input.Replace(",", "")
            .Replace(".", "")
            .Replace("<", "")
            .Replace(">", "")
            .Replace("'", "")
            .Replace("\"", "");
    }

    private string m_field1;
    private string m_field2;

    public string Field1 
    {
        get { return m_field1; }
        set { m_field1 = SanitizeText(value); }
    }

    public string Field2 
    {
        get { return m_field2; }
        set { m_field2 = SanitizeText(value); }
    }

    public decimal Field3 { get; set; }

    public TestLineItem() { }

    public TestLineItem(object field1, object field2, object field3)
    {
        m_field1 = (field1 ?? "").ToString();
        m_field2 = (field2 ?? "").ToString();

        if (field3 == null || field3.ToString() == "")
            Field3 = 0m;
        else
            Field3 = Convert.ToDecimal(field3.ToString());
    }
}
```

*Then open the worksheet and load into a 2D array*:

```
// using OExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
var app = new OEXcel.Application();
var wbPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Book1.xls");

var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(wbPath);
var ws = (OEXcel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

// there are better ways to do this... 
// this one's just off the top of my head
var rngTopLine = ws.get_Range("A1", "C1");
var rngEndLine = rngTopLine.get_End(OEXcel.XlDirection.xlDown);
var rngData = ws.get_Range(rngTopLine, rngEndLine);
var arrayData = (object[,])rngData.Value2;

var tc = new TestClass();

// since you're enumerating an array, the operation will run much faster
// than reading the worksheet line by line.
for (int i = arrayData.GetLowerBound(0); i <= arrayData.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    tc.LineItems.Add(
        new TestLineItem(arrayData[i, 1], arrayData[i, 2], arrayData[i, 3]));
}

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
var fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    "Book1.xml"));
xs.Serialize(fs, tc);

wb.Close();
app.Quit();
```

*The generated XML output will look something like this*:

```
<TestClass>
  <LineItems>
    <TestLineItem>
      <Field1>test1</Field1>
      <Field2>some&amp;lt;encoded&amp;gt; stuff here</Field2>
      <Field3>123456.789</Field3>
    </TestLineItem>
    <TestLineItem>
      <Field1>test2</Field1>
      <Field2>testing some commas, and periods.</Field2>
      <Field3>23456789.12</Field3>
    </TestLineItem>
    <TestLineItem>
      <Field1>test3</Field1>
      <Field2>text in &amp;quot;quotes&amp;quot; and &amp;#39;single quotes&amp;#39;</Field2>
      <Field3>0</Field3>
    </TestLineItem>
  </LineItems>
</TestClass>
```

Comment: Thank you. I made this work with some slight modifications. It's relatively quick. The slowest part is actually opening the file. Reading the file is very fast

Answer (score 2):

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Another option is Interop which requires Excel to be installed locally BUT [Interop is not supported in sever-scenarios by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).

*Any library-based approach to deal with the Excel-file directly is way faster than Interop in my experience...*

Comment: I was under the impression the openXML parsing method only worked on values that were all numeric.  Got that idea form here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg575571.aspx

Comment: @Brandon sorry, but your impression is plain wrong... the OpenXML SDK can deal with all types of Excel cells/content (like Text etc.) - follow the links above and see the API description etc.